# Auth::token() method auto implemented in laravel 4?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, token, csrf

I was just watching videos on creating an account and using `Auth::token` for CSRF protection.
It's weird that in the form I created I didn't use `Auth::token()` and somehow when I'm checking out my browser it automatically has the hidden token field.
Anyone know how could this happen? I tried using both Firefox and Chrome and both of them are doing the same thing.

In my form I simply have

```
{{ Form::open() }}
{{ Form::submit('Create account') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

P.S. if I added `Form::token()` right above `Form::close` and I inspect element in page I see two tokens even though they are the same.  One on top of the submit button and one below.

Just curious if anyone know how it's doing that and does that mean I don't have to insert the `Form::token()` method manually anymore?

Answer (score 0):

`Form::open()` literally inject token into form for you.
No need to take care of this while using `Form::open()`.